# Azure webapp startup host address 127.0.0.1:80 An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: sockets, azure, startup

I have an issue with appears to occur randomly (however i suspect it occurs when starting up the application or changing the application settings). The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:80
```

The particular error in my case occurs when trying to generate a authentication token using Identity Framework by making requests to the following url:

https://domainname/api/token

Note that the api/token url is specified within the owin pipeline > OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions > TokenEndpointPath. This get set on startup of the application.

From my understanding 127.0.0.1:80 is azures localhost and is forbidden for us to access, i'm not sure why its defaulting to localhost as a domain, my educated guess is something is happening during the startup that's first setting the host to localhost.

My question is does anyone else get this on startup (while the site is warming up) for azure web apps?
Have i configured something incorrectly for me to be getting this behavior?
I know this is a little open ended but is there anything i can do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That is the well-known issue described in the [official documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). You may not to access not just a 127.0.0.1, but i suspect that the problem is even a little different - it looks like something is wrong with the :80 port usage. IIS use that port, and i would try to change the port used by your app.
However, from your description is not clear who is that guy who tries to do that - your app tries to do something with the 80 port, or the Azure WebApp functionality.

Please try to start from the eliminating the possibility of some renewing events by enabling Always On in the Azure Web App setting. It will make your web app always on, and will help to understand if that is caused by the service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the call itself is being made from the web app to a web API hosted within the same site. I can also confirm that the setting to always keep the site on is enabled.

Comment: Hm. Do they use the same port? Or WebApp and WebApi are hosted as a different slots in the same Web App?

Comment: Their hosted in the same web app. I have just tried hard coding the host URL, will see what happens.